# Add Multiple Calendar events (non-recurring) to Android

Tags: android, calendar, android-contentprovider

I want to add multiple canlendar events to calendar programmatically (content provider). Lets say there are some events associated with a work. Those events can be single or multiple. And the multiple ones can be recurring (once in a month) or non-recurring (random dates). Basically I have a list of dates, which I need to add to calendar in such a way, that they are associated with their work.

Example:
Work1: General meeting.
Dates1: 12.01.2011, 06.02.2012, 17.03.2012 ... (random multiple dates)

Work2: Monthly Report.
Dates2: 25.01.2011, 26.02.2012, 21.03.2012 ... (random multiple dates)

So all the dates1 should be associated together as they all belong the work1. Because if user wants to edit location, alarm or description, then he/she should be able to do it for all dates with a single action (like in recurring events).

I was thinking to add the first event and get the returning event-id and add next dates with the same event-id. But I am not sure whether this is the correct way.

How can I do this correctly? I could not find anything about this problem on anywhere.

(Using event_id gives this error: E/AndroidRuntime(3649): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column 'event_id' is invalid)

Answer (score 0):

I did not find any solution for this. What I did was, keeping id of each event of the same work and gave the user the opportunity to delete events of the same work through my application.